# sys.stdout logging writes to previously created files too

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger class in python (=3.7) as:

```py
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, fpath=None):
        self.console = sys.stdout
        self.file = None
        if fpath is not None:
            mkdir_if_missing(os.path.dirname(fpath))
            self.file = open(fpath, 'w')

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()

    def write(self, msg):
        self.console.write(msg)
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.write(msg)

    def flush(self):
        self.console.flush()
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.flush()
            os.fsync(self.file.fileno())

    def close(self):
        self.console.close()
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.close()
```

and I'm trying to print and write multiple files in a for loop like:

```py
for i in range(5):
    sys.stdout = Logger(os.path.join('logs', f'log_{i}.log'))
    print('test')
```

it prints to console correctly but it keeps writing to `log_0`, `log_1`, ... as well. So my printed files are like:

`log_0.log`:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

`log_1.log`:

```
test
test
test
test
```

`log_2.log`:

```
test
test
test
```

`log_3.log`:

```
test
test
```

`log_4.log`:

```
test
```

I used to fix this when I was using FileHandlers. But since there are no handlers, how I can close previous files and just write to new files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
self.console = sys.stdout
```

you're saving the previous `Logger` instance in `self.console`, because the loop sets `sys.stdout` to a `Logger`.

You should use a class attribute rather than an instance attribute, and just set it once when the class is created.

You shouldn't call `self.console.close()`, since that will close the original `sys.stdout`.

```
class Logger(object):
    console = sys.stdout

    def __init__(self, fpath=None):
        self.file = None
        if fpath is not None:
            mkdir_if_missing(os.path.dirname(fpath))
            self.file = open(fpath, 'w')

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()

    def write(self, msg):
        self.console.write(msg)
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.write(msg)

    def flush(self):
        self.console.flush()
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.flush()
            os.fsync(self.file.fileno())

    def close(self):
        if self.file is not None:
            self.file.close()
```

Comment: that makes sense. but now when I run the main script it complains: `r.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: Get rid of `self.console.close()`

Comment: great tip. it works now. Thank you so much for your help.